# Cygwin compiler header include error (OpenSSL)

Tags: header, openssl, makefile, cygwin

I have installed Cygwin under Windows 8 to compile a small C project. Although OpenSSL package has been included within Cygwin's installation, when compiling the project (using the command **make -f makefile** in Cygwin terminal) I get an error:

```
make -s -C lib -f local.mk
CC auth.c
In file included from auth.h:9:0,
                 from auth.c:18:
session.h:11:24: fatal error: openssl/dh.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/dh.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
local.mk:35: recipe for target 'auth.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [auth.lo] Error 1
makefile:79: recipe for target 'lib' failed
make: *** [lib] Error 2
```

Looking at Cygwin's folders, Openssl headers are located in

```
/cygwin64/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/include/openssl
```

Neither coping the **openssl** folder within **/cygwin64/usr/include** nor adding the directive

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/cygwin64/usr/i686-pc-cygwin/sys-root/usr/include/openssl
```

into the makefile has solved the problem. It keeps throwing the same error.... What can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have solved the problem:

1. Wiped out Cygwin 64 and started from scratch with 32 bit version
2. Installed Openssl latest from openssl.org
3. Compiled. No more problems!

Answer (score 2):

Are the header files there?  If not, the OpenSSL header files are in the package called `openssl-devel`.

Comment: Yes the headers are there, however the compiler will ignore them. Unless the installation fialed somewehere

Comment: I had a mingw openssl package installed or something, and when i installed openssl-devel, everything worked fine. (aka this answer worked for me, thanks)

Comment: The openssl-devel package is obsolete. Selecting this package for installation will cause the libssl-devel package, which replaces this one, to be installed instead.